# How to disable pycharm shared variables visibility?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When I debug in pycharm, sometimes I see only the variables in the scope, and sometimes, I see all the variables, like "_ *file* _" and "__ doc __".

How to only see my declared variables?

[image]

Comment: someone can help?